# Trouble joining generate_series timestamp without time zone on a field that's timestamp without timezone

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to figure out a way to report how many people are in a location at the same time, down to the second. 
I have a table with the id for the person, the date they entered, the time they entered, the date they left and the time they left. 
example:

```
select unique_id, start_date, start_time, end_date, end_time
from My_Table
where start_date between '09/01/2019' and '09/02/2019'
limit 3

"unique_id" "start_date"    "start_time"    "end_date"  "end_time"
989179  "2019-09-01"    "06:03:13"  "2019-09-01"    "06:03:55"
995203  "2019-09-01"    "11:29:27"  "2019-09-01"    "11:30:13"
917637  "2019-09-01"    "11:06:46"  "2019-09-01"    "11:06:59"
```

i've concatenated the start_date & start_time as well as end_date & end_time so they are 2 fields

```
select unique_id, ((start_date + start_time)::timestamp without time zone) as start_date, 
((end_date + end_time)::timestamp without time zone) as end_date
```

result example:

```
"start_date"
"2019-09-01 09:28:54"
```

so i'm making that a CTE, then using a second CTE that uses generate_series between dates down to the second.

The goal being, the generate series will have a row for every second between the two dates. Then when i join my data sets, i can count how many records exist in my_table where the start_date(plus time) is equal or greater than the generate_series date_time field, and the end_date(plus time) is less than or equal to the generate_series date_time field.

i feel that was harder to explain than it needed to be.

in theory, if a person was in the room from 2019-09-01 00:01:01 and left at 2019-09-01 00:01:03, i would count that record in the generate_series rows 2019-09-01 00:01:01, 2019-09-01 00:01:02 & 2019-09-01 00:01:03.

When i look at the data i can see that i should be returning hundreds of people in the room at specific peak periods. but the query returns all 0's.

is this possibly a field formatting issue i need to adjust?

Here is the query:

```
with CTE as (
select unique_id, ((start_date+start_time)::timestamp without time zone) as start_date, 
((end_date+end_time)::timestamp without time zone) as end_date
from My_table
where start_date between '09/01/2019' and '09/02/2019'
),
time_series as (
    select generate_series( (date '2019-09-01')::timestamp, (date '2019-09-02')::timestamp, interval '1 second') as date_time
)
/*FINAL SELECT*/
select date_time, count(B.unique_id) as NumPpl
FROM (
    select A.date_time
    FROM time_series a
)x
left join CTE b on b.start_date >= x.date_time AND b.end_date <= x.date_time
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

[(partial) result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYEch.png)

Thank you in advance

i should also add i have read only access to this database so i'm not able to create functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple version: `b.start_date >= x.date_time AND b.end_date <= x.date_time` will never be true assuming `end_date` is always after `start_date`.

Longer version: You also do not need a CTE for the `generate_series()` and there is no reason for selecting all columns and all rows of this CTE as a subquery. I would also drop the CTE for your original data and just join it to the seconds (**NOTE**: this does somehow change the query, since you might now take those entries into account, where `start_date` is earlier than `2019-09-01`. If you do not want this, you can add your condition again to the join condition. But I guess this is what you really wanted). I also removed some casts which were not needed. Try this:

```sql
SELECT gs.second, COUNT(my.unique_id)
FROM generate_series('2019-09-01'::timestamp, '2019-09-02'::timestamp, interval '1 second') gs (second)
LEFT JOIN my_table my ON (my.start_date + my.start_time) <= gs.second
    AND (my.end_date + my.end_time) >= gs.second
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Thank you @Islingre That worked perfectly! Much appreciated!!

Comment: You are welcome @JasonSmith and you are invited to leave an upvote and an acception ;)